# Possibility for deadlock to occur during IPC call

Tags: android

I have a `MainActivity` which will issue IPC call to a remote `AutoCompleteService` service.

During execution of `AutoCompleteService`'s IPC function, the service will issue another IPC call back to `MainActivity`.

### MainActivity.java

```
// Receive IPC call from AutoCompleteService.
private StockInfoObserver.Stub stockInfoObserver = new StockInfoObserver.Stub() {

    @Override
    public void update(StockInfo stockInfo) throws RemoteException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.i(TAG, android.os.Process.myPid() + " : MainActivity receive ipc call : " + Thread.currentThread().getId());
    }

};

...
...
...

// Issue IPC call to AutoCompleteService.
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // Test on API.
        try {
            Log.i(TAG, android.os.Process.myPid() + " : MainActivity start issue IPC call to remote service : " + Thread.currentThread().getId());
            // autoCompleteApi.handle will issue IPC call to remote service.
            autoCompleteApi.handle("abc");
            Log.i(TAG, android.os.Process.myPid() + " : MainActivity end issue IPC call to remote service : " + Thread.currentThread().getId());
        } catch (RemoteException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

});
```

### AutoCompleteService.java

```
private AutoCompleteApi.Stub autoCompleteApi = new AutoCompleteApi.Stub() {    
    private List<StockInfoObserver> stockInfoObservers = new ArrayList<StockInfoObserver>();

    @Override
    public void handle(String string) {
        Log.i(TAG, android.os.Process.myPid() + " : AutoCompleteService start receive ipc call : " + Thread.currentThread().getId());
        try {
            for (StockInfoObserver stockInfoObserver : stockInfoObservers) {    
                Log.i(TAG, android.os.Process.myPid() + " : AutoCompleteService start IPC call to MainActivity : " + Thread.currentThread().getId());
                // stockInfoObserver.update will issue IPC call back to MainActivity
                stockInfoObserver.update(null);
                Log.i(TAG, android.os.Process.myPid() + " : AutoCompleteService end IPC call to MainActivity : " + Thread.currentThread().getId());
            }
        } catch (RemoteException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Log.i(TAG, android.os.Process.myPid() + " : AutoCompleteService end receive ipc call : " + Thread.currentThread().getId());
    }

    @Override
    public void attachStockInfoObserver(StockInfoObserver stockInfoObserver)
            throws RemoteException {
        if (stockInfoObservers.contains(stockInfoObserver) == false) {
            stockInfoObservers.add(stockInfoObserver);
        }
    }
};
```

My initial expectation is that, **deadlock will occur**. This is due to my observation. When issuing an IPC call, the issuer will only return from IPC call, after the IPC receiver finished its IPC function execution.

1. `MainActivity` issues IPC call to `AutoCompleteService` through `autoCompleteApi.handle`.
2. `MainActivity` will now wait till `AutoCompleteService` finished its execution.
3. `AutoCompleteService` issues IPC call to `MainActivity` through `stockInfoObserver.update`.
4. `AutoCompleteService` will now wait till `MainActivity` finished its execution.
5. However, `MainActivity`'s thread is still waiting, there are no thread which will perform `update` function.
6. Both processes keep waiting for each others.

However, the above doesn't occur. This is the Log I'm getting. Everything just work flawless.

```
// Log in MainActivity TAG
3930 : MainActivity start issue IPC call to remote service : 1
3930 : MainActivity receive ipc call : 1
3930 : MainActivity end issue IPC call to remote service : 1
```

---

```
// Log in AutoCompleteService TAG
3961 : AutoCompleteService start receive ipc call : 494
3961 : AutoCompleteService start IPC call to MainActivity : 494
3961 : AutoCompleteService end IPC call to MainActivity : 494
3961 : AutoCompleteService end receive ipc call : 494
```

---

But I don't really understand. **If the MainActivity thread (with Id 1) is not returning from a function call (`autoCompleteApi.handle`), how can it "jump" over to execute another function (`update(StockInfo stockInfo)`)?**

I would be expecting **MainActivity receive ipc call** being printed by different thread. Not the thread with Id 1. If not, deadlock should occur.

In case you are interested to try to out, kindly download the complete source code right here : https://www.dropbox.com/s/8hd7v5acjd213l1/jstock-android2.zip

Comment: My guess would be that LogCat can't keep up with process change here. It really makes no sense you receive IPC callback back to MainActivity before logs from AutoCompleteService are written.

Comment: Sorry. The log are from 2 different TAG.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An interesting question. My first thought that the incoming IPC call is handled on a different thread (as it normally would occur with an incoming IPC call) turned out to be wrong in this specific scenario.

Looking at the execution stack when the incoming call arrives one sees (most recent stack frames at the top):

```
MainActivity$1.update
MainActivity$1.onTransact
MainActivity$1.execTransact         <- this gets called by the incoming IPC call
BinderProxy.transact                <- this is where the outgoing IPC call is made
AutoCompleteApi$Stub$Proxy.handle
MainActivity$3.onClick
...
```

So all is taking place in the same thread. The incoming call looks like a subroutine call of the outgoing call. The magic to make this possible is happening in native code (or maybe in the kernel). There is an [interesting paper by Thorsten Schreiber](https://www.nds.rub.de/media/attachments/files/2011/10/main.pdf) explaining some of the internals of the Binder mechanism. Unfortunately it does not the discuss the back call to the same process as it happens in this example.

There is a small remark about the feature in [this blog post](http://lukejin.wordpress.com/2011/03/13/android%E4%B8%AD%E7%9A%84binder/):

> Note that the original thread may also receive BR_TRANSACTION commands while it is waiting for a reply. This represents a recursion across processes the receiving thread making a call on to an object back in the original process. It is the responsibility of the driver to keep track of all active transactions, so it can dispatch transactions to the correct thread when recursion happens.

Maybe there is more to find in the [OpenBinder website](http://www.angryredplanet.com/~hackbod/openbinder/docs/html/), the root of the Android Binder implementation.

Comment: But if you look at my log, you will realize same thread is being run in MainActivity.

Comment: @YanChengCHEOK: Then you are mis-interpreting your log. For example, you are logging process IDs and thinking that they are thread IDs.

Comment: @CommonsWare: Why say so? I thought `Thread.currentThread().getId` does prove same thread is being run? Note, I log both process id (front) and thread id (back)

Comment: @YanChengCHEOK That's a good point, I need to investigate this more closely.

Comment: @YanChengCHEOK: Whoops, sorry -- I was focused on the left-hand column of numbers, which are your process IDs. That being said, AIDL IPC calls do not come in on the main application thread, where `setOnClickListener()` is called, so I still believe that Henry is correct, and something is amiss in your logging.

Comment: @Henry I upload the complete project files just in case you're interested.

Comment: @YanChengCHEOK yes please.

Comment: @Henry Looking forward more input from you :)

Comment: @YanChengCHEOK I have updated the answer with what I found out. The "recursion across processes" is a special case in the Binder implementation.